# Why wasn't the proposal for decimal floating point arithmetic accepted into C++0x?

Tags: c++, c++11, standards

Why wasn't the [decimal type](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2849.pdf) accepted into C++0x (now C++11) either as a fully fledged type or as a class?

They worked on it from [2005](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/) after a fairly scathing [critique in 2004](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2004/n1567.htm) and the last paper for it was [2009](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/) and looking through it, [seems pretty complete](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2849.pdf).  Were the concerns raised in 2004 the basis for rejecting it despite most of the issues being resolved?

There isn't even an implementation of it in [boost](http://www.boost.org/) (though there is some [discussion](http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2012/05/193217.php) of it in the mailing list earlier in the year).

Comment: And yes, I know Intel has an implementation of IEEE754-2008.

Comment: Rejecting what? The standards committee approved ISO/IEC TR 24733:2011, " Extensions for the programming language C++ to support decimal floating-point arithmetic".

Comment: But you can't use an in built decimal type in C++11, which is what the question was/is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C++11 was very rushed for time. They really couldn't go around including every old thing that came along. In 2009 it was becoming obvious that it would be quite late, and they simply didn't consider it. However, [N3407](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3407.html) indicates a proposal to accept it for (hopefully) C++17.

Comment: Do you know, by any chance, if any compiler vendor working on this enhancement? Or, are there any libraries which can be very close to this specification?

Comment: Nope. There does not seem to be a particularly high demand for this feature set.

Comment: C++11 wasn't any more rushed for time than any other standards effort. But like all projects, if you want to finish you have to stop adding things.

Comment: If my understanding is correct, it could also be possible that a Technical Report would be published, allowing compilers to start implementing it before 2017.